# How to access cordova.js from remote website

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, web

I use the Ionic 2 app to access to my mobilewebsite. In config.xml I use the following constrution:

```
<content src="http://192.168.1.15/mobilesiteapp/" />
```

So I had to open my local website. But I need to load cordova.js in index.html file because I need the functions from it for some cordova pluguins.
How to do with because a following code in my index.html does not work:

```
<!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
<script src="cordova.js" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I now, cordova.js can't be loaded form external content, as it part of the core system. Ionic implement this file in order to load plugin. 
Do you expect your mobile website access Cordova plugin? I don't see this as a valid option.

Answer (score 1):

It works, you need to copy cordova.js script and its plugin on server.